# How to exclude folder from Visual Studio 2013 Find?

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I am using an ASP MVC project. Both the /Content and the /Script folder has a Kendo subfolder which contains enormous sized files. As a consequence when I am using solutionwide Find operation it takes literally minute(s) and even the VS UI is frozen and became **unresponsive** *(btw this is a shame in 2015, I am using a 8 core / 16Gigs machine and all files on SSD, anyway)*.

As a workaround it would be great to exclude the 2 Kendo subfolders from Find operations. How can I accomplish this?

Note: using file wildcards, and not searching in any .css and .js files is not an option, because I have my own .js and .css files and searching in those files is mandatory.

Answer (score 1):

In order to exclude subfolders, you can create a custom Folder Set. Click the ellipse (...) for the "Look in" option in the "Find and Replace" dialog.

Related answer: [Visual Studio Search in Selected Folders or File Types Only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/795691/visual-studio-search-in-selected-folders-or-file-types-only)

Comment: Many thanks. Although this is not exactly "exclude", so this means must by repeated by solution basis, and also in case if the excludable has many siblings, then I have to add dozens of folders, +  the tree above which also can be complex

Comment: Yep, being able to exclude folders directly would be a nice feature in VS. I've used this method as a last resort on my projects.

Comment: Maybe an external util, which allows a bit more sophisticated include/exclude functionality, then generates and persists the selection(s)  for VS would be useful.

Answer (score -1):

If the problem is that the gui is lagging. Try Find In Files -> Result Options -> Display file names only = true. Hopefully that is good enough.